# JPA performance on empty DB

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-integration

I have a spring integration int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway using a jpa query.
the insert takes a less than a second and reading a row that exists takes less than a second.
however when I search for a value that does not exist in the DB or if I search an empty DB the query takes more than a minute to complete which causes a timeout in my application.
I have tried a native query as well and the same result occurs.  I ran the native query in pgadmin and took 17 ms to complete.

Can anyone shed any light on this phenomenon for me?  The integration flow starts with a gateway that has each of the crud actions mapped to a specific channel.  the service interface takes in the entity and returns a type Message.

```
<int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway id="select-in"
    entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory" request-channel="eselect-in-channel"
    jpa-query="${db.query.select.in}" expect-single-result="false" >
    <int-jpa:parameter expression="payload.myKey" name="myKey"/>
    <int-jpa:parameter expression="payload.myIds" name="myIds"/>
</int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway>
```

here is the jpa query:

```
db.query.select=SELECT x FROM MyEntity x WHERE x.myId IN :myIds AND x.myKey = :myKey
```

--EDIT--

The application is still in development so everything is running on localhost.
The DB size has not went over 5 or 10 records in the testing I have done so far.
The entire DB consists of one table with myId and myKey as the composite PK.
the rest of the table consists of a timestamp denoting the insert time and a type_description of type varchar

-- EDIT --

After looking at the AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler the Handle message internal method has a result of null so nothing is published to the output channel. In my case there is no output/reply channel so an empty list should be returned to the caller, which is my gateway.  but because the the record does not exist the result is null and the result handler never gets called and the caller is never notified and finally times out.

```
if (result != null) {
        MessageHeaders requestHeaders = message.getHeaders();
        this.handleResult(result, requestHeaders);
    }
    else if (this.requiresReply) {
        throw new ReplyRequiredException(message, "No reply produced by handler '" +
                this.getComponentName() + "', and its 'requiresReply' property is set to true.");
    }
    else if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("handler '" + this + "' produced no reply for request Message: " + message);
    }
```

I was under the impression that an empty list was supposed to be returned when no results were found
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/124469-jpa-retrieving-outbound-gateway-produced-no-reply-when-zero-entities-in-database

Comment: Can you give more information. for example, how many records you have in db, what are the indexes. Is application server separated from database server (or they are in the same server) and so on.

Comment: I suggest you take a thread dump while it's "hung" (jstack or visualVM).

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell could you comment on the below answer?  I would really like to get your input.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so here is my HACK to make this work:

```
<gateway id="persistence-gateway"
    service-interface="com.service.JPAService"
    default-request-timeout="${default.request.timeout}" default-reply-timeout="${default.reply.timeout}"
    error-channel="jpaErrorChannel">
    <method name="executeSelectIn" request-channel="select-in-channel"/>
</gateway>

<channel id="select-in-channel" />

<int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway id="select-in"
  entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory" request-channel="select-in-channel"
  jpa-query="${db.query.select.in}" expect-single-result="false" >
    <int-jpa:parameter expression="payload.myKey" name="myKey"/>
    <int-jpa:parameter expression="payload.myIds" name="myIds"/>
</int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway>

<!-- Error preprocessing -->
<channel id="jpaErrorChannel" />

<payload-type-router id="jpaErrorRouter" 
    input-channel="jpaErrorChannel" 
    default-output-channel="jpaErrorProcessorChannel">
    <mapping type="org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyRequiredException" channel="jpaErrorPassthroughChannel"/>
</payload-type-router>

<channel id="jpaErrorPassthroughChannel" />

<transformer id="jpaErrorPassthroughTransformer" 
    input-channel="jpaErrorPassthroughChannel"
    expression="T(java.util.Collections).emptyList()"/>
```

and here is the jpa query:

```
db.query.select=SELECT x FROM MyEntity x WHERE x.myId IN :myIds AND x.myKey = :myKey
```

I don't like it but for now it works.  I am of the opinion that this a bug in the spring AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler but I would like to know what the Spring Guru's think.

Comment: The simpler workaround is here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3333. And as you it isn't fixed yet. We'll probably address it soon.

Comment: Thanks @Artem - another simple work around (in this case) is to set `default-reply-timeout="0"` on the gateway and treat `null` the same as an empty list.